# How to generate a proper hyperlink by leveraging link_to()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

```
<h3>Social Media Handles: (<%=link_to 'Seel All Social Media', influencer_influencer_social_media_handles_path(@influencer)%>)</h3>
        <ul>
        <% @influencer.influencer_social_media_handles.each {|social_media_handles| %>
              <li><strong>Social Media Name:</strong> <%=social_media_handles.social_media_name%><br />

                <%=link_to(social_media_handles.social_media_handle) %>
              </li>
          <% } %>
        </ul>
```

This `<%=link_to(social_media_handles.social_media_handle) %>` is actually a link to a twitter page i.e `http://twitter.com/#!/SrBachchan`. But when I click on it nothing happens. How can I make this link working so it will take me to a twitter page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for a comprehensive usage of `link_to` tag in rails.

```
<%= link_to 'Twitter Profile', social_media_handles.social_media_handle %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is `link_to(:body, :url, :options)`

So, you should:

```
<%= link_to 'Twitter Profile', social_media_handles.social_media_handle %>
```

Assuming that social_media_handles.social_media_handle returns "http://twitter.com/#!/SrBachchan" that will generate:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/SrBachchan">Twitter Profile</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Righn now link open in a same window how I would open into a new window??